# VS Code doesn't show upstream branches to pull from

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have forked a repository on GitHub to work on, and I want to keep my local repo up to date as I work on it. In VS Code, I select "Pull from..." which lists two remotes, `origin` and `upstream`, then asks for a branch to pull from. If I select `origin`, the available branches are `origin/HEAD` and `origin/master`. However, if I select `upstream`, no branches are listed. Is there a way I can pull from an upstream branch in VS Code?

Comment: Use the command line instead, please. That way we can coherently interrogate your repo. It sounds like you've got two remotes and you've merely forgotten to `git fetch upstream` but hard to say because VSCode is in the way.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I'm new to using git so I didn't realize I had to fetch before doing a pull

Comment: You might want to take some time to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

Comment: do you just need fetch info about that remote first? Have you done that yet? (Ex. `git fetch --all` I think)